# Removing consecutive asc/desc sequences from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

am thinking of a pandaistic way (not a loop) to remove all consecutive positives or negative pct changes. So assuming i have a dataframe like this:

`df=pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,5,4,3,2,4,5,6,7,8,9])`

i would want to remove all in between points where there is consecutive ascending/descending sequences. the end output would be [1,5,2,9]. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you mean ascending or descending sequences.

Comment: Sorry about that, have amended it to make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `scipy.signal`'s `argrelextrema` function here.

```
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

arr = df.iloc[:, 0].values
i = argrelextrema(arr, np.greater_equal)[0]
j = argrelextrema(arr, np.less_equal)[0]

arr[np.sort(np.r_[i, j])]
```

```
array([1, 5, 2, 9])
```

If you want to preserve the DataFrame structure, you may instead use `iloc` to index

```
df.iloc[np.sort(np.r_[i, j])]

    0
0   1
3   5
6   2
12  9
```

Comment: Would it be possible to maintain the index of the dataframe?

Comment: @smallcat31 Again? Aha, this is the third question of yours that I've answered. Well, you're welcome, and here's to three more ;-)

Answer (score 1):

With the other words you need to choose items where `A[i-1] > A[i] < A[i+1]` or `A[i-1] < A[i] > A[i+1]`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,4,5,6,7,8,9])
numbers_list = df[0].values.tolist()
df = pd.DataFrame([item[1] for item in filter(lambda x: ((x[2] < x[1] > x[0]) or (x[2] > x[1] < x[0])), zip(numbers_list, numbers_list[1:], numbers_list[2:]))])
```

For this items, you also have to concat the first and last items from your given array.